# Absolute value circuit around a non-zero value

Tags: analog, circuit-design

I have searched for a few hours on the internet and in some circuit design books, but have been thusfar unable to find a circuit that produces absolute value around a number other than zero. Does anyone here know of such a circuit? An example IO would be:
At Vin = 10, Vo = 10
At Vin = 9, Vo = 11
At Vin = 11, Vo = 11

I'm hoping to accomplish this with a single absolute value circuit, rather than subtracting 10 beforehand, taking the absolute value, and adding 10 or offsetting the result.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you just take the normal absolute value circuit and offset its power supply?

Comment: @Jake - Every component you add will introduce error.

Comment: What’s the real application?

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone here know of such a circuit?

The circuit below can do what you want: -

[image]

You can set input voltage \$e_2\$ to be at 10 volts and A3 (an instumentation amplifier) can have its reference pin set to 10 volts (not shown in the circuit above).

\$Z_L\$ can be a resistor and it could equal R. The instrumentation amplifier can have gain set to unity by not fitting the gain resistor hence the equation becomes: -

$$e_O = |e_1 - e_2|+ e_2$$

Comment: @Jake I've altered my answer - I didn't originally see that part. However, you will still need a 10 volt reference voltage.

Answer (score 2):

In general you can just take an absolute value circuit and substitute a 10V reference for whatever it uses for a zero reference (which may be a power supply or something else). You will have to take care that there is enough power supply headroom, of course.

Here is a modification of a [standard circuit](http://www.analog.com/en/design-center/reference-designs/circuit-collections/lt1001-precision-absolute-value-circuit.html):

[image]

to do what you want with, an LTspice simulation:

[image]

The blue trace is the input, the green is the output. Where the output goes flat at the beginning and end, it is saturating near the positive rail (+20V in this case).

This particular circuit does need a negative supply, however the +10V reference input is high impedance so you may be able to use a voltage divider etc.