# Simulating absolute value circuit in TINA-TI

Tags: voltage, simulation, single-supply-op-amp

I am looking to build an absolute value circuit using a pair of op-amps, hopefully using a single supply and would like to simulate my design using TINA-TI.

The ultimate aim is to measure the voltage difference between an input and a reference voltage that is not necessarily ground. The modified LT1001 circuit in the answer to [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/388626/absolute-value-circuit-around-a-non-zero-value) would be okay, but it is dual supply.

TI provide a useful [application bulletin](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa068/sboa068.pdf) with various designs for absolute value circuits. Figure 5 in the application bulletin offers a nice single supply variant. I have reproduced it here in case of a stale link later.

[image]

I have entered the design into TINA-TI - I think without errors, but the simulation is not working with the output swinging immediately to mid-supply.

[image: TINA-TI schematic entry]

[image: Output waveform]

Why aren't I seeing the waveform as shown in the application bulletin?

Also at the bottom of the clip (below Figure 5.1) it contains the sentence *"Notice that the input range of the circuit is 4V below the power supply rail."*. 
What does this mean - the diagram shows the input to be -4V to +4V and the output 0 to 4V for a 5V supply?

Comment: Well, for one thing, your input voltage is substantially less than that used in the example design, where the input was an 8Vₚ₋ₚ sine wave. By 4V below the supply rail it means you can safely have an input of -4V; 4V below the negative supply rail (which is ground in this case).

Comment: I'm also inclined to ask, where did you get these specific values for the resistors from? I haven't bothered doing any math, but it's possible your problem lies there.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense now (0V being a power supply rail in this case). The values come from a table at the back of the application bulletin. There are various options, I used the "Lowest Cost" one. Originally, I had an OPA2337 in the circuit but changed it as per the note under Figure 5.1 (both gave the same [wrong] output waveform).

Comment: I have updated the output image to show the 8Vp-p input. The output remains the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found your problem.

[image]

See where the arrow's pointing? That indicates that your *positive* supply rail should connect there.

We all make that mistake. Who knows why the symbol has that on the bottom; I guess it's probably been flipped from its original orientation.

Comment: I know it's not good SE etiquette, but really thanks for this! I had been staring at it for 2 hours without seeing that one.

Comment: It's a mistake I've made countless times, and yet I still never notice it quickly.

Comment: "Who knows why the symbol has that on the bottom; I guess it's probably been flipped from its original orientation." No, that's a characteristic of TINA. All op amps are that way. As far as I can tell, it's done that way to make it easier to position power supply voltages. A default voltage source will have the + at the top, and it can be installed just below the op amp. Likewise, the - pin of a source can be installed just above an op amp. I personally don't agree with the choice, but they didn't ask me.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I would agree with you that it seems like the wrong decision, but I suppose I can see why they did it if that was their thought process.